# How to see $\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}\frac{(x^{\alpha}-1)}{x^{\alpha-1}-1}>0$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

I want to prove that $$\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}\frac{(x^{\alpha}-1)}{x^{\alpha-1}-1}>0\text{ where }\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\text{ and }x\in(0,\infty).$$ I checked this function is increasing on $(0,\infty),$ but I have a problem with its value near $0.$

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Also $a\neq 0,1$ I guess?

Comment: For $\alpha=0$, consider $\log x.$